# Default size of Form in Bootstrap React

Tags: reactjs, forms, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap for an app. And I am grouping a form with a button in a flex container with justify-content set to space-between. [image: 1]

Why is the size of the form set to 200px? Is this the default value? [image: 2]

```
<Form className='d-flex  justify-content-start mb-4'>
    <Form.Control
        type='search'
        placeholder='Search'
        className='me-2'
        aria-label='Search'
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
            setSearchValue(e.target.value);
        }}
    />
</Form>
```

Comment: Check the class and parent div for the answer. Actually, your question need details and clarity as code or something

Comment: I have added now the code, sorry for the inconvenience